# Hello, is it possible customize the snackbar in Moto G 2nd Gen?

Tags: customization

I am right handed but when I turn the phone, I would like to change the snackbar to the left, is it ONLY to the right?

Comment: If by "snackbar" you're talking about [this](http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/android-snackbar-with-action-callback-undo.png)... Isn't it always at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Snackbar by default appears at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Developers had to implement it to their snack bar in that way! You cannot do it for a application by using any other application I hope.